# Polynomials and dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i have this exercise about polynomials and dictionaries which i did (see below) but i am sure there is a better and easier way to solve it (for question 2 and 3). can anyone show me another way to approach question 2 or 3? Thanks.

here is the exercice:

In this exercise we want to work with polynomials of any degree. Each polynomial can be represented by a dictionary, whose keys correspond to the powers of x, and the values ​​to the coefficients. For example, to represent the polynomial x ^ 6 + 3 * x ^ 2, we can use the dictionary: {6: 1, 2: 3}

**1.** Write a function evaluer(p, x) that takes a polynomial p and a number x into arguments, and returns the value of polynomial at point x.

Execution example:

> > > evaluer({3: 1, 1: 2, 0: -1}, 2)

OUT: 11

**2.** Write a function somme_polynomes(p1, p2) which takes two polynomials (dictionaries) into arguments and which
returns a new dictionary representing the sum of the two polynomials p1 and p2.

Execution example:

> > > somme_polynomes ({3: 1, 2: 1, 0: 1}, {4: 2, 2: 3})

OUT: {0: 1, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 2}

**3.** Write a function produit_polynomes(p1, p2) that takes two polynomials as arguments and returns the product of two polynomials in a new dictionary.

Execution example:

> > > produit_polynomes ({3: 1, 2: 1, 0: 1}, {4: 2, 2: 3})

OUT: {2: 3, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2}

here is what i did:

```
# 1)

def evaluer(p,x):
    c = 0
    for key,value in p.items():
        c += value*(x**key)
    return c

# 2)

def somme_polynomes(p1,p2):
    p3 = {}

    for key,value in p1.items():
        for k,v in p2.items():
            p3.update({key:value})
            p3.update({k:v})

    for key in p1:
        if key in p2:
            add = p1[key]+p2[key]
            p3.update({key:add})
            if add == 0:
                del p3[key]
    return p3

# 3)

def produit_polynomes(p1,p2):
    p3 = {}
    for key,value in p1.items():
        for k,v in p2.items():
            if key+k in p3:
                p3[key+k] += value*v
            else:
                p3.update({key+k:value*v})

    return p3
```

Comment: So what do you want us to do?  Write the code for you?  I suggest you write a more specific question.

Comment: Your code looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, here are alternative ways of doing it using more of Python's language (generator expression, dict comprehension) and library (`itertools`, `collections`):

```
def evaluer(p, x):
    return sum(v * x**k for k, v in p.items())

def somme_polynomes(p1, p2):
    return {k: p1.get(k, 0) + p2.get(k, 0) for k in p1.keys() | p2.keys()}

import itertools as it
from collection import defaultdict

def produit_polynomes(p1, p2):
    p3 = defaultdict(int)
    for k1, k2 in it.product(p1, p2):
        p3[k1+k2] += p1[k1]*p2[k2]
    return dict(p3)
```

If you want to avoid importing any modules then `produit_polnomes()` could be written without the conditional as:

```
def produit_polynomes(p1,p2):
    p3 = {}
    for k1, v1 in p1.items():
        for k2, v2 in p2.items():
            p3[k1+k2] = p3.get(k1+k2, 0) + v1*v2
    return p3
```

Answer (score 0):

Exercise 2 can be done in a more Pythonic way by using set union for keys and dict comprehension for sums:

```
def somme_polynomes(p1, p2):
    return {p: p1.get(p, 0) + p2.get(p, 0) for p in p1.keys() | p2.keys()}
```

Exercise 3 on the other hand is best done using nested loops aggregating products to the sum of keys, which is what you are already doing. The only slight enhancement I would make is to use the `setdefault` method to avoid the `if` statement:

```
def produit_polynomes(p1,p2):
    p3 = {}
    for key,value in p1.items():
        for k,v in p2.items():
            p3[key + k] = p3.get(key + k, 0) + value * v
    return p3
```

Comment: You can't use `setdefault()` this way.

Comment: You still don't need `setdefault()`, a simple `get()` would do the same.

Comment: Yeah. Wasn't thinking straight. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `set(p1) | set (p2)` use `p1.keys() | p2.keys()`, since a keys view object implements set operations